# ClipToOutline and CornerRadii

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-drawable

I've to make a view with radius on some corners. For that, I apply a `background` to the view, and set `clipToOutline` at true :

```kotlin
val shape = GradientDrawable()
shape.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE

// Set rounded corners for topLeft and bottomRight
shape.cornerRadii = floatArrayOf(radius, radius, 0f, 0f, radius, radius, 0f, 0f)

view.background = shape
view.clipToOutline = true
```

The issue is that the view doesn't clip with the background, but if I use `cornerRadius` instead of `corderRadii` , it works.

How can I set a `cornerRadii`and clip with outline ?

**SOLUTION :**

For this case, I've created `RoundedCornerPath` class :

```kotlin
class RoundedCornerPath(
    topLeft: Float = 0f,
    topRight: Float = 0f,
    bottomRight: Float = 0f,
    bottomLeft: Float = 0f
) {

    private val path = Path()
    private val radii = floatArrayOf(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)

    init {
        setRadius(topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft)
    }

    fun getRadius() : Float {
        return radii.maxOrNull() ?: 0f
    }

    /**
     * Change radius values
     * Need to call RoundedCornerPath.rebuildPath and View.invalidate() after this method
     *
     * @param topLeft: Top left radius in Px
     * @param topRight: Top Right radius in Px
     * @param bottomLeft: Bottom left radius in Px
     * @param bottomRight: Bottom Right radius in Px
     */
    fun setRadius(@Px topLeft: Float,
                  @Px topRight: Float,
                  @Px bottomRight: Float,
                  @Px bottomLeft: Float) {

        radii[0] = topLeft
        radii[1] = topLeft

        radii[2] = topRight
        radii[3] = topRight

        radii[4] = bottomRight
        radii[5] = bottomRight

        radii[6] = bottomLeft
        radii[7] = bottomLeft
    }

    /**
     * Call View.invalidate() after this method to update outline
     *
     * @param containerWidth: Container Width in Px, call View.measuredWidth
     * @param containerHeight: Container Height in Px, call View.measuredHeight
     */
    fun rebuildPath(@Px containerWidth: Int, @Px containerHeight: Int): Path {

        path.reset()

        path.addRoundRect(
            RectF(
                0f,
                0f,
                containerWidth.toFloat(),
                containerHeight.toFloat()
            ),
            radii,
            Path.Direction.CW
        )

        path.close()

        return path
    }

    fun getPath(): Path {
        return path
    }
}
```

Then, I add this class in my custom view, and I create a fonction to update my outline :

```kotlin
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    ...
    private val borderPath: RoundedCornerPath = RoundedCornerPath(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)

    // Needed to apply outline
    override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas) {

        canvas.clipPath(borderPath.getPath())
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas)

    }

    init {

        clipToPadding = true

        val shape = GradientDrawable()
        shape.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
        shape.setColor(Color.WHITE)

        background = shape

    }

    ...

    private fun applyCorners(
        radius: List<Float>,
        width: Int,
        height: Int) {

        val (topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight) = radius

        borderPath.setRadius(topLeft = topLeft, topRight = topRight, bottomLeft = bottomLeft, bottomRight = bottomRight)
        borderPath.rebuildPath(width, height)
        invalidate()

        // Apply new Background
        (background as? GradientDrawable)?.cornerRadii = floatArrayOf(
            topLeft, topLeft, topRight, topRight, bottomRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft, bottomLeft
        )

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override getOutlineProvider() function

Comment: Thank for your answer, I've found a solution for this case, I update my post now !